# Use RxJava to chain observables under complex condition

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I want to build a splash screen in Android. While the splash screen is loading, an image loader will try to get a newer splash image from the server, and then the newer image will be saved to local storage and be used as splash screen image for next launch. And the splash screen will stay for 5s, then it jumps to the Main Activity. Also we need a count-down counter on the splash screen.

I am able to use Observable.interval to get the splash screen dismissed on completion and to update the counter on next emit. But should I load the image when the counter starts and the timeout for image retrieving task is also 5s, if we could not get the image, then cancel the task ?

```
splash_sub = Observable
            .interval(SPLASH_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS) //to emit event every 1s
            .take(SPLASH_DURATION) //limit the event number to 5, i.e. 5s to complete
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) //timer and event emitting run in background
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //subscriber callback run in UI thread
            .subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    dismissSplash(); //dismiss the Splash Screen and enter the Main Activity
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Long aLong) {
                    Log.d(TAG, aLong.toString());
                    textView.setText(String.format("%s", aLong));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to load the image WHILE you are waiting the splash to dismiss.

the easier option you have, simply create your:

```
imageDownloadObservable
  .timeout(SPLASH_DURATION * SPLASH_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .subscribe();
```

and both will happen at the same time.

If you want dismiss the splash when the picture is loaded or 5s ( the first that happens ) it could be done by using the merge operator.